# Mac development, objective-c: can I detect when user switch tasks like closing a window, activating to another window?

Tags: objective-c, macos

I am developing a desktop application that capture computer activities on mac osx using objective-c. I know it's possible to capture it when user presses on the keyboard and mouse position. But I don't know how to detect when user switches tasks on computer, like closing a window (of other applications), activating another window (of other applications)?

Does anyone have any experience in that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, via the [Accessibility](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Accessibility/Conceptual/AccessibilityMacOSX/) system. For example the [NSAccessibilityMainWindowChangedNotification](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nsaccessibilitymainwindowchangednotification?language=objc).